# Does Firebase's Remote Config store the latest values locally?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I can't find a straight answer on the interwebs, and I suspect this is because the answer is negative.
Does the Firebase Remote Config SDK store locally the values it got from the API, and restore those in the event it can't contact the server again, or are the provided default values used ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the this behavior is confirmed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config#how_does_it_work) every time you see it refer to "caching" values.

> Remote Config includes a client library that handles important tasks like fetching parameter values and **caching** them, while still giving you control over when new values are activated so that they affect your app's user experience.

[Also](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios#fetch-values):

> Any values that you set on the backend are fetched and **cached** in the Remote Config object. ... This example fetches values from the Remote Config backend (not **cached** values) ...

A lack of caching would make the application behave very strangely, as a blip in network availability could make it immediately behave very differently compared to the last time it ran.  That would be bad, and so the cache exists.

Comment: @surnamet When you build your app, a set of default values is included in the binary, so that the app can start on any device even when it doesn't have a network connection. Then when the client/SDK retrieves values from the server, it caches those locally too - as Doug answers.